# Getting HTML as plain text

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc, rich-text-editor

I am taking HTML as input from a page using Tinymce(Rich Text editor), and saving  input to SQL server , While retrieving the data form database and passing it  to  view ,all html tags and content are showing as plain text.

I am using asp.net core MVC.

Comment: use `Html.Raw(yourmodel.value)` to render HTML content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you would want to use [Html.Raw()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)

Html.Raw() with render the HTML string you pass to it as markup on the page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ,sir .
Is there any Tag helper for this in MVC 6?

Comment: In your view, you can just use @Html.Raw(Model.Property)

Comment: I used @Html.Raw() in my view and it is working fine, but I just want  to know is there any alternative of @Html.Raw()  (Which is a HTML helpers) in Tag Helpers.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, is there a reason Html.Raw() is undesirable?